# How to count/summarize Cognos LIST grouped columns?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have this LIST having the following data items in the following order: DataItemA, DataItemB, DataItemC, DataItemD, DataItemE, DataItemF, DataItemG, DataItemH
Groups on :DataItemA, DataItemB, DataItemC, DataItemD

Structure :
List Header : using DataItemA
List Footer : Using DataItemB, DataItemC and DataItemD

DataItem E : is a metric and is called Metric1
DataItem F : is a metric and is called Metric2

I clicked Metric1 column and clicked on the TOTAL button from the menu and it automatically created TOTALS for each any of the grouped data items(grouped DataItemB, DataItemC and DataItemD)

I the try to the same with the Metric2 but the TOTAL displaying is the same (wrong) for each of the grouped date items. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for any valuable feedback!

[image: Data sample]
[image: Same data sample but better print screen image]
[image: After clicking on the following menu]
[image: Metric 1 properties]
[image: Metric 2 properties]

Comment: It's the same, but what is it?  Maybe posting sample output would help.

Comment: Hi, actually the column subTotal, Total for Metric is ok BUT whe doing the same on METRIC2, the same amount$$ apears for rhe subtotal and Total! Meaning the summarization isn't working correctly. I see 10 and then 10 and then 10 for example when i should be seeing 10 and then 50 and then 100 for example.

Comment: The total of the values in the top group is 20865.  The total of the values in the bottom group is 18000.  The total of all of the values is 38865.  I don't see where your total of 159499 could have come from.  Maybe you are not providing enough information.  Can you reproduce the problem using the samples?

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you all know that the reason it wasn't correctly displaying because the some data items needed to come from another query subject the automatic total is now working as expected.

Regards and thanks to all!